# Select count from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables: ToDoList & ToDotasks

I need to write a query that will return me the column ot ToDoList as well as a count of incomplete tasks i.e. where taskstatus=0 for the ToDotasks table

My query:

```
SELECT *,(select count(*) from todotasks where taskstatus = 0 group by
listid) as TotalIncomplete FROM dbo.ToDoList
```

Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

ToDoList:

```
    ListID  ListName
       1    List 5600
       2    List 22
       3    List 30
       4    List 4
       5    List 1
```

ToDotasks

```
taskid ListID   taskStatus
    3      2    0
    6      3    0
    14     3    0
    16     3    0
    19     4    1
    36     1    0
    38     1    1
    39     1    0
    40     2    0
    41     2    0
```

What I am after:

```
    ListID  ListName   TotalIncomplete
       1    List 5600       2
       2    List 22         3
       3    List 30         3
       4    List 4          0
       5    List 1          0
```

Comment: What isn't working with the query you have? IOW, what are you asking of is?

Comment: You have SELECT **, should be SELECT *

Comment: Yeah for some reason stackoverflow was hiding one *...so i added 2

Comment: I need a third column which is calculated based on incomplete task count

Comment: `1    List 5600       3`  HOW is this last column 3, should it not be 1 or  2?

Comment: I see no `TOTAL` as in your query in your "what I am after".  Your query table names do NOT match your description.  Please clarify your question explicitly, computers do not  guess and code does not either even when it "seems" obvious.  Do you need a reference to `ListId` in the sub query to the one in the outer one? hint.

Comment: It would improve the Quality of your question if the sample data matched with the desired output.

Comment: Hi toonice, I have update the tables and table names to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT ToDoList.ListID AS ListID,
       ToDoList.ListName AS ListName,
       COUNT( incompleteTasks.ListID ) AS IncompleteTaskCount
FROM ToDoList
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ListID AS ListID
    FROM ToDoTasks
    WHERE taskStatus = 0
) incompleteTasks ON ToDoList.ListID = incompleteTasks.ListID
GROUP BY ToDoList.ListID
ORDER BY ToDoList.ListID;
```

The logic I used was...

To get a count of incomplete tasks we would first need a list of those tasks that have a `taskStatus` of `0`.  The `taskid` will be irrelevant to the count and once tested so will `taskStatus` be irrelevant.  Therefore this list only needs to include each qualifying task's `ListID`.  I have given this list the name `incompleteTasks`.

`ToDoList LEFT JOIN incompleteTasks` will give us a table consisting of each value from `incompleteTasks` with its corresponding values from `ToDoList`.  Where a record from `ToDoList` does not have any corresponding records in `incompleteTasks` we get the values from `ToDoList` accompanied by a `NULL` value.

By grouping the `LEFT JOIN`ed list on its value of `ListID` from `List` we achieve a grouping that corresponds with our desired output.  We then use `COUNT()` to count the number of times that `ListID` appears in our joined list's field from `incompleteTasks`.  Note : `COUNT()` does not count `NULL` values.

The list resulting from the above can then be sorted by the value of `ListID` from `List` using `ORDER BY ToDoList.ListID`.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: Hi toonice, I have update the tables and table names to make it more clear

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'ToDoList.ListName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained

Comment: An error was spotted and corrected.  I have also updated the table and field names.

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Only thing missing was that I had to group by ToDoList.ListName as well.

Comment: That's a surprise.  `ToDoList.ListID` will only ever have one corresponding value of `ToDoList.ListName`, therefore there should be no need to group by it as well.  Did my answer not work properly with just `ToDoList.ListID`?

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty straight forward.. Here is the solution

```
select ToDoList.lisid, ToDoList.lastname, count(ToDoTasks.taskstatus) from
ToDoList JOIN ToDoTasks ON ToDoList.listid = ToDoTasks.listid 
where ToDoTasks.taskstatus = 0
group by ToDoList.listname,ToDoList.listid
```

Updated Query with your table names....
Hope this helps. Cheers !!!

Comment: Hi Jack. This is exactly what I need but it doesn't return any ToDoList rows where there is no corresponding todotasks data or where there is no incomplete todotasks

Comment: Thanks Jack. 
     
This is exactly what I need but it doesn't return any ToDoList rows where there is no corresponding todotasks data or where there is no incomplete todotasks

Comment: Ok no problem. So just edit my query and put a LEFT JOIN instead of just the JOIN. This will solve your issue.

Comment: I tried with LEFT join...but it still doesn't show the missing rows

Comment: @RahulBhatia - As long as data / in this case LISTID exists in both the tables it should bring back the data. Can you post the answer so that I can manipulate accordingly ?
We are using a LEFT JOIN so u will get everything from the ToDoList table with Nulls in the taskstatus if there is no matching data,

Comment: @RahulBhatia- You are going and giving negative marking on the answers even after saying this is exactly what you were lookin for? I am marking this question down for you.

Comment: Jack James, How do you know that it was RahulBhatia?

Comment: Jack James, Also your code would not return anything for `ListID`'s `4` and `5`, whereas the Customer is asking for those records from `List` with a corresponding count of `0`.

Comment: @toonice - this is a crapful of place because of people like you. Just because u wanted your answer to be counted in you mark people's answers down ? This is utterly ridiculous. .

Comment: Actually, I am quite happy for your answer to be chosen as the preferred answer.  My comment was aimed at suggesting a way in which you could improve your answer and thus improve your answer's chances and in so doing to best serve the Questioner.  My apologies for not making that more clear in my previous Comment.

Comment: Also, I did not mark everyone's answer (including mine) down.  And there is no way of finding out who did short of asking and hoping that they own up to it, which would be against SO rules and protocols.

Comment: @toonice - it was a bit frustrating even after helping people to get marked down, some people do not know what they are looking for and ask the wrong questions and when they do not receive an answer as per their expectations make a mess. Well i guess this is a good platform to code and test your patience at the same time..